# Should I iterate a vector by iterator or by access operator?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, stdvector

I have a vector declared as

```
std::vector<int> MyVector;
MyVector.push_back(5);
MyVector.push_back(6);
MyVector.push_back(7);
```

How do should I use it in a for loop?

By iterating it with an iterator?

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=MyVector.begin(); it!=MyVector.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Vector element (*it): " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Or by its access iterator?

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<MyVector.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "Vector element  (i) : " << MyVector.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

In examples I found on internet both of them are used. Is one of them superior to the other under all conditions? If not, when should I prefer one of them over the other?

Comment: Doesn't the name *"iterator"* help with the decision? By the way, I hope you have a clear understanding of what `std::vector::at` does and why you use it in your code. If using `std::vector::at` instead of `std::vector::operator[]`, iterators will most probably always be faster (disregarding any other advantages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first format is ***more generic*** format for iterating over standard library containers so it is more common and intuitive. If you need to change your container then this iterating code remains unimpacted.It will work for every standard library container type, thus it gives you more generic code.

In second format, `std::vector::at()` checks for the bounds each time it gets called on every iteration, so it may be a little ***detrimental to performance***. This overhead is not present in the first format as there is no bounds checking involved.Note that same is the case with using `operator[]`.
Note the performance lag though is not as much as you will notice it unless you are operating on a huge data.

Comment: Concur. Bottom line: use iterators for scanning, at() for random access. you'll be glad you did.

Comment: @CraigNelson No, I won't. If I access the vector out of bounds, then shame (and UB) on me, but don't make me check its size each and every time. In debug mode I'll get an assertion anyway (at least in VC++).

Comment: @ChristianRau if you're random-accessing a sequence without knowing the bounds thats your business. I prefer to know that ahead of time. You're quite right, however. I meant to say [] rather than at(). touche.

Comment: The iterator or `operator[]` will normally do bounds checking as well (although you can usually turn it off if necessary for performance reasons).  The difference between their bounds checking and that in `at()` is that an error will crash the program (which is usually what you want), rather than triggering an exception which you can't reasonably handle.

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::vector's [] operator` is probably faster because using `std::vector::at()` inside a for loop checks the vector's size twice (in the for loop and in std::vector::at()'s bounds checking).

The first method can be used in other containers and thus can help you much when you change your container type.

If you use C++11, use range-based loops.

Answer (score 2):

First if you have C++11, use a range-based for:

```
for (auto i : MyVector)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Or `BOOST_FOREACH` in C++03:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int& i, MyVector)
{
  std::cout << i;
}
```

Or `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(MyVector.begin(),
          MyVector.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

As for, the question at hand, `at()` checks that the index is within bounds and throws an exception if it isn't. So, do not use it unless you need that extra checking. The first way you have it is standard and works well. Some people are pedantic and even it write it like so:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=MyVector.begin(), end = MyVector.end(); it!= end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Vector element (*it): " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

In the above I cached the `end` iterator instead of calling `end()` each loop. Whether this actually makes a performance difference or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one is superior to the other" (except that you almost never
want to use `at()`—`at()` is only appropriate if there is
something you can really do to recover from the error).  The use of
iterator vs. index is largely one of style, and the message you're
passing.  The more idiomatic C++ way of doing things would be the
iterator, but people coming from other backgrounds (for example,
mathematicians) will find indexing more idiomatic.

There are where there is a real distinction:

- The iterator idiom will work with other types of containers.  This
  might be relevant if there is a real possibility that you use other
  containers.
- The indexing idiom can use a single index for several different
  containers.  If you're iterating through several `vector` with the same
  size, using the indexing idiom makes it clearer that you're accessing
  the same element in each of the `vector`.  (Again, this seems to occur
  most often in mathematical applications.)
- Finally, any time you're really doing random access, or calculating
  the element in any way, using indexes is probably more intuitive.  (In
  such cases, you probably want to do the calculations in `int`, only
  converting to `size_t` at the last moment.)